# Flutter debug, FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter

Why am I getting the following error? All of a sudden it started giving this error. and strangely i started getting this error in all my projects

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1070

What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1m 6s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Did you try `flutter clean` and rebuilding the app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70534320/4353594

Comment: i tried everything still same error

Comment: Have you upgraded your Flutter SDK?

Comment: yes but nothing has changed

Comment: try running flutter run --no-sound-null-safety

Comment: still same error :(